# R - how to programmatically filter data from dataframe

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have dataframe, something like this

```
test <-
  data.frame(
    product = c("car", "phone", "car", "computer"),
    country = c("us",  "us", "uk", "world"),
    price = c(12,  44, 87, 78)
  )
```

I call markdown document like this

```
rmarkdown::render(
  input = "sale_template.Rmd",
  params = list(
    test= test
  ),
  output_file = format(month, "%Y-%m-%d")
)
```

. What I'd like to achieve is:

- filter data by product
- create summary for each product type (create new row with product text "total", sum columns in price and another columns)
- put product value as header of block

  ### phone

  ```
  datatable(
    params$test,
    rownames = F,
    options = list(
      pageLength = 99,
      dom = "t",
      columnDefs = list(list(className = "dt-center", targets = "_all")),
      ordering = F
    ))
  ```

  ### phone

  ```
  datatable(
    params$test,
    rownames = F,
    options = list(
      pageLength = 99,
      dom = "t",
      columnDefs = list(list(className = "dt-center", targets = "_all")),
      ordering = F
    ))
  ```

Please keep in mind that my product column have dozens of different values an can't been filtered manually.

For similar but with ggplot graphs I'm using this.

````
plotlist <- split(sales, sales$month)
plotlist <- lapply(plotlist, function(df){
  ggplot(df, aes(x = month, y = type, fill = type)) +
    geom_col(position = "dodge")
})

## Month 1

```{r}
print(plotlist[[1]])
```

## Month 2

```{r}
print(plotlist[[2]])
```
````

But I have no idea how to call my dataframes with unknown length/list length in mardkown and use datatable function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Rmd and knitr, you can create a template for what you want for each project and then call it from your main file using `knit_expand` and `unlist`, like:

*SubTemplate.Rmd*

````
```{r}
thisdf <- df %>% filter(project == {{project}})
thisproject <- as.character({{project}})
```

### `r thisproject`

blah blah blah

```{r maketable}
# do stuff in here with thisdf to output your table
```
````

*MainFile.Rmd*

````
```{r}
#all of your other code for the Rmd
```
```{r eachone}
    ## Generate report for each 
    products <- sort(unique(df$product))
    src <- lapply(products, function(product) knitr::knit_expand(file = "SubTemplate.Rmd"))
```
`r knitr::knit(text = unlist(src))`
````